# IsLocationOnPath not working

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, polyline

I am working to make a check in my app that whether user follow given route map or not. I am checking user change in current position and have called isLocationOnPath in my location changed method as following

```
 try {
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (handelrCheck) {
                        if (visitedPoints.size() != allQuestions.size() && QuestionOnTheRoute() < mCircle.getRadius() && !isDone() && Integer.parseInt(allQuestions.get(questionNumber).getSequence())==sequenceFlag) {
                            visitedPoints.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(allQuestions.get(questionNumber).getLat()), Double.parseDouble(allQuestions.get(questionNumber).getLng())));
                            showPopup(); // show question pop up when it is inside user radius
                            //add viisited check point to menu
                            VisitedcheckPoint++;
                            sequenceFlag++;
                            heading5.add("" + VisitedcheckPoint);
                            for (int i = 0; i < heading5.size(); i++) {
                                if (heading5.size() > 1) {
                                    heading5.remove(0);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else if (checkCompleteSurvey()<mCircle.getRadius()) { // when user complete survey
                            handelrCheck = false;
                            handlerForQuestions = null;
                            showAllAnswers(); // show all ansers to user when user complete survey

                        }
                        else if(!PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(new    LatLng(AppPreferences.getLatitude(mCurrentActivity),AppPreferences.getLongitude(   mCurrentActivity)),routePoints,true,10)){
                            Toast.makeText(mCurrentActivity, "Please follow the selected route for experiment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

    //                        else if (visitedPoints.size() ==    databaseHandler.getQuestionOnRoute().size()) { // when user complete survey
    //                            handelrCheck = false;
    //                            handlerForQuestions = null;
    //                            showAllAnswers(); // show all ansers to user    when user complete survey
    //
    //                        }
                    }

                    if (handlerForQuestions != null)
                        handlerForQuestions.postDelayed(this, pooltime);
                }

            };

            handlerForQuestions.postDelayed(r, pooltime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can anyone help me??

Comment: no one here to help me???

Comment: did you find a solution?